# jQuery Flip Effect on Image/Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code...

Once an image is clicked it is animated (e.g. Resized and moved) to look like it is flipping over to reveal another image. This works perfectly fine when the code is applied to images, but when I want to apply it to a containing div, that contains

tags and a few more images, all goes wrong.

**THIS WORKS:**

```
<img alt="" src="image_1.jpg" id="image1" />
<img alt="" src="images_2.jpg" id="image2" />
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var margin = $("#image1").width()/2;
    var width = $("#image1").width();
    var height = $("#image1").height();

    $("#image2").stop().css({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'});

    $("#image1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).stop().animate({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'},{duration:500});
        window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#image2").stop().animate({width:''+width+'px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:'0px',opacity:'1'},{duration:500});
        },500);
    });

    $("#image2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).stop().animate({width:'0px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:''+margin+'px',opacity:'0.5'},{duration:500});
        window.setTimeout(function() {
        $("#image1").stop().animate({width:''+width+'px',height:''+height+'px',marginLeft:'0px',opacity:'1'},{duration:500});
        },500);
    });

});
```

**THIS DOESN'T WORK**

```
<div class="containerOne">
    <img src="image_1.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="image_3" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="containerTwo">
    <img src="image_2" alt="" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var margin = $(".containerOne").width()/2;
    var width = $(".containerOne").width();
    var height = $(".containerOne").height();

    $(".containerTwo").stop().css({
       width:'0px',
       height:''+height+'px',
       marginLeft:''+margin+'px',
       opacity:'0.5'
    });

    $(".departmentProducts").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('.containerOne').stop().animate({
            width:'0px',
            height:''+height+'px',
            marginLeft:''+margin+'px',
            opacity:'0.5'
        }, { duration:500 });
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".containerTwo").stop().animate({
                width:''+width+'px',
                height:''+height+'px',
                marginLeft:'0px',
                opacity:'1'
            },{ duration:500 });
        },500);
    });

    $(".departmentProduct").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('.containerTwo').stop().animate({
            width:'0px',
            height:''+height+'px',
            marginLeft:''+margin+'px',
            opacity:'0.5'
        },{ duration:500 });

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $(".containerOne").stop().animate({
                width:''+width+'px',
                height:''+height+'px',
                marginLeft:'0px',
                opacity:'1'
            },{ duration:500 });
        },500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code look well, but i think that you are using **animate()** on your div container of 
, you image not change his visual properties, because his properties steel the same, I recomend to you check this link https://api.jquery.com/animate/ ,
look this simple example how animate a div.

```
   <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>animate demo</title>
    <style>
    div {
    background-color: #bca;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     </head>
    <body>
    <button id="go">&raquo; Run</button>
     <div id="block">Hello!</div>
      <script>
     // Using multiple unit types within one animation.
     $( "#go" ).click(function() {
     $( "#block" ).animate({
     width: "70%",
     opacity: 0.4,
     marginLeft: "0.6in",
     fontSize: "3em",
     borderWidth: "10px"
     }, 1500 );
     });
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

**Hope Hepls.**

Comment: So how would you apply this to my code in my original post. I can't see how this can be causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

See this jQuery plugin [here](http://guilhemmarty.com/flippy/). Named Flippy and seems to be lightweight.

Comment: I have looked at this, but the animation appears odd in FireFox. The flipped element doesn't stay inside the containing element during animation. This is why I decided to make my own.

Comment: This plugin offends my eyes